# Regex For Matching URLs that Share Portions of the Same Format

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a Regex for a Cypress test to intercept a call to the backend. I have two calls, both `PUT`s, that are made to endpoints that look like this:

Call 1: /api/{randomId}
Call 2: /api/{randomId}/approval

I need a regex that matches the first but not the second, and a regex that matches the second but not the first.

The second regex is easy: `.+\/api\/.+\/approval` will match the second URL but not the first:

[image: regex test result]

The first regex though is tough because everything I've tried so far matches both URLs. For example, `.+\/api\/.+` matches both URLs:

[image: regex test result]

I'm not really familiar with regexes and have tried several options on regexr (like a negative lookahead so that if the random ID is followed by a `/` it shouldn't match) but nothing has worked so far.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With negative lookahead, you can do something like this:

```
\/api\/(?!.+?\/approval).+
```

Basically, put the thing you don't want (so, a bunch of chars followed by `\approval`) entirely in the lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

To test for the first URL you can test for just the random pattern, followed by end of string:

```js
const input = [
  '/api/qwerty123',
  '/api/qwerty123/approval',
  'https://example.com/api/random99',
  'https://example.com/api/random99/approval',
];
const regex1 = /^.*\/api\/[^\/]+$/;
const regex2 = /^.*\/api\/[^\/]+\/approval$/;

input.forEach(str => {
  let m1 = regex1.test(str);
  let m2 = regex2.test(str);
  console.log(`${str}: regex1 ${m1}, regex2 ${m2}`);
});
```

Output:

```
/api/qwerty123: regex1 true, regex2 false
/api/qwerty123/approval: regex1 false, regex2 true
https://example.com/api/random99: regex1 true, regex2 false
https://example.com/api/random99/approval: regex1 false, regex2 true
```

Explanation of `regex1`:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `.*` -- greedy scan
- `\/api\/` -- literal `/api/`
- `[^\/]+` -- 1+ chars that are not `/`
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

Explanation of `regex2`:

- `^.*\/api\/[^\/]+` -- same as `regex`, expect for trailing anchor
- `\/approval` -- literal `/approval`
- `$` -- anchor at end of string